# How to efficiently perform equality query on key-value data with duplicate keys allowed?

Tags: postgresql, key-value, postgresql-performance, external-sorting

I have the following situation:

1. Data = around 400 million (string1, string2, score) tuples
2. Data size ~ 20gb, doesn't fit in memory.
3. Data is stored in a file in csv format, and not sorted by any
   field.
4. I need to efficiently retrieve all tuples with a particular
   string, e.g. all tuples s.t. string1 = 'google'.

How do I design a system such that I can do this efficiently ?

I have already tried postgresql with a B-tree index and GIN index, but they aren't fast enough (> 20-30 seconds) per query.

Ideally, I need a solution which sorts the tuples by string1, stores them in sorted fashion and then run binary search, followed by sequential scan for retrieval. But, I don't know which database or system implements such functionality.

UPDATE:
Here's the postgres details:

I bulk-loaded data into postgres using COPY command. Then I created two indices on string1, one b-tree and one GIN. However, postgres is not using either of them.

Create tables:

```
  CREATE TABLE mytable(
 string1 varchar primary key, string2 varchar, source_id integer REFERENCES sources(id), score real);
  CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;
  CREATE INDEX string1_gin_index ON mytable USING gin (string1 gin_trgm_ops);
  CREATE INDEX string1_index ON mytable(lower(string1));
```

Query plan:

```
     isa=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE select * from mytable where string1 ilike 'google';
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                                 
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on public.mytable  (cost=235.88..41872.81 rows=11340 width=29) (actual time=20234.765..25566.128 rows=30971 loops=1)
   Output: hyponym, string2, source_id, score
   Recheck Cond: ((mytable.string1)::text ~~* 'google'::text)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 34573
    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on string1_gin_index  (cost=0.00..233.05 rows=11340 width=0) (actual time=20218.263..20218.263 rows=65544 loops=1)
     Index Cond: ((mytable.string1)::text ~~* 'google'::text)
   Total runtime: 25568.209 ms
   (7 rows)

 isa=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE select * from isa where string1 = 'google';
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                         
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Seq Scan on public.mytable  (cost=0.00..2546373.30 rows=3425 width=29) (actual time=11692.606..139401.099 rows=30511 loops=1)
    Output: string1, string2, source_id, score
    Filter: ((mytable.string1)::text = 'google'::text)
    Rows Removed by Filter: 124417194
    Total runtime: 139403.950 ms
    (5 rows)
```

Comment: "*a solution which sorts the tuples by string1, stores them in sorted fashion and then run binary search*" which is exactly what a B-Tree index is doing. Please read [tag:postgresql-performance], the **[edit]** your question and add the missing information

Comment: If the query parameter returns more than a few percent of the table then a sequential scan will be done regardless of the indexes.

Comment: One way of speeding up string comparisons is to use `collate "C"` for the key if that doesn't contain any international characters. Another often used approach is to not index the strings, but a hashvalue of the strings to make the index smaller and thus lookups in the index faster

Comment: Also there is query time and server -> client data transport time.

Comment: string1,string2 probably belong to the same domain, so one string-table plus a bridge-table with two FKs  (and containing the score) seems natural.

Comment: If the table is stable (or close to) you can [`cluster`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-cluster.html) it according to an index to make faster sequential scans in a range.

Comment: Postgres is not using the indices, I assume mainly because a reasonable number of rows are to be returned. Ideally, this would be much faster if the data was sorted contiguously based on string1. @a_horse_with_no_name : I know that B-tree does keep the data sorted, but does it also re-shuffle the data to store it contiguously, so that it can be scanned sequentially instead of multiple accesses to the index?

Comment: actually, the LIKE query can be ignored. I only need the equality query for my work. As you can see, it doesnt use the index and takes significantly larger time than ilike query, that shouldnt be right.

Comment: by contiguous, I mean that I want all the tuples with same string1 to be stored contiguously on the hard disk. That's the only way in which I could achieve significant speed up. But, I dont think creation of B-tree index ensures that.

Comment: That would be perfect place to use database partitioning with a hash function which uses string1.

Comment: So what's keeping you from using partitioning?

Comment: Because, for now I only have one disk and technically I don't need partitioning yet. I am researcher and don't plan to use this in production anytime soon. I was trying to see if there is a quick way of storing such data and retrieve it efficiently. I am now looking into partitioning to see how it helps.

Comment: `CREATE INDEX string1_index ON mytable(lower(string1));` - that index will only be used if the expression is also used in the query, e.g. `where lower(string1) = 'google'`

Comment: aah, that's right. I didn't know about that restriction. That significantly speeds up. Thanks :).

Comment: You might want to read: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause